# msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail send an email using high priority and low priority

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

I am using SQL Server procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` to send an email. I have some emails that should be instant and some emails can be delayed. So in short I want to give priority to each email. Is it possible to achieve this using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible with SQL server, the mail queue can't be prioritized.

Comment: What about importance parameter? Is it not for priority? Is not not same as MailPriority.High?

Comment: Database mail uses FIFO service broker queues internally but I don't believe there is a set the message priority. The importance parameter is only used for the message header, AFAIK. Personally, I would use a standard SMTP client for non-trivial needs.

Comment: @user960567 The `@importance` parameter isn't part of any Internet Message Format RFCs (822, 2322, 5322, 6854). Non-Microsoft mail servers aren't likely to pay attention to it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so no way to prioritize an email?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the red exclamation point to show on the email you can use

@importance = 'High'